# LIMIT rows from the latest - JOINED tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I got two tables, customer_ledger and users.
I'm using PHP for my simple log-in program wherein the users input their username and password. Once the account is valid, it will show them their billing history. So I joined the two tables to link the username with the contract number in the other table.

My problem now is, how to display their (5) latest billings based on the field (LDGR_PER_COV_TO)? I created a MySQL query but it gave me a different result.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    customer_ledger.LDGR_YEAR,
    customer_ledger.LDGR_MONTH,
    customer_ledger.LDGR_PER_COV_FROM,
    customer_ledger.LDGR_PREV_RDNG,
    customer_ledger.LDGR_PER_COV_TO,
    customer_ledger.LDGR_PRES_RDNG,
    customer_ledger.LDGR_KWH_USED,
    customer_ledger.LDGR_BILL_AMOUNT
FROM
    customer_ledger
INNER JOIN users
ON customer_ledger.LDGR_CONTRACT_NO=users.LDGR_CONTRACT_NO
WHERE users.Username = 'kim'
ORDER BY customer_ledger.LDGR_PER_COV_TO ASC
LIMIT 5
```

this result will give me rows starting from the top most record. I would like it to display from the bottom-going up (latest record - top record).

Can anyone help?

Comment: What kind of data contain in customer_ledger.LDGR_PER_COV_TO column ?

Comment: billing date.. i sorted it according to this field since i want to display the latest bills

Comment: ORDER BY customer_ledger.LDGR_PER_COV_TO DESC seems like it would reverse the order.

Comment: It seems Kent is right

Comment: ok i tried this one but the topmost record would be the latest. i would want it that the latest record will be in the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use alises for better readibility,
Then use DESC in place of ASC

```
    SELECT   cl.LDGR_YEAR,         cl.LDGR_MONTH,
             cl.LDGR_PER_COV_FROM, cl.LDGR_PREV_RDNG, 
             cl.LDGR_PER_COV_TO,   cl.LDGR_PRES_RDNG, 
             cl.LDGR_KWH_USED,     cl.LDGR_BILL_AMOUNT 
    FROM     customer_ledger AS cl INNER JOIN users AS u 
                                   ON cl.LDGR_CONTRACT_NO=u.LDGR_CONTRACT_NO 
    WHERE    u.Username = 'kim' 
    ORDER BY cl.LDGR_PER_COV_TO DESC LIMIT 5
```

New Query ::

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT   cl.LDGR_YEAR,         cl.LDGR_MONTH,
                 cl.LDGR_PER_COV_FROM, cl.LDGR_PREV_RDNG, 
                 cl.LDGR_PER_COV_TO,   cl.LDGR_PRES_RDNG, 
                 cl.LDGR_KWH_USED,     cl.LDGR_BILL_AMOUNT 
        FROM     customer_ledger AS cl INNER JOIN users AS u 
                                       ON cl.LDGR_CONTRACT_NO=u.LDGR_CONTRACT_NO 
        WHERE    u.Username = 'kim' 
        ORDER BY cl.LDGR_PER_COV_TO DESC LIMIT 5
    ) AS a
    ORDER BY a.LDGR_PER_COV_TO
```

Comment: ok i tried this one but the topmost record would be the latest. i would want it that the latest record will be in the bottom.

Comment: Edited : please check new query in ANSWER ,  If it still doesn't work, I suggest you to accomplish this thing at applicaion side, 

Fetch the array from this query, and use array_reverse with help of the link, 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_reverse.asp

Or
use reverse FOR LOOP.

Comment: @Kimsoyens, please vote-up if this has solved your issue!